# Disabling back button in android only for a specific action

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to disable back button only if a certain action is completed.But if i override onBackPressed() and call it within my required action , the back button  is disabled right from the beginning.I want the back button to be disabled only if a certain action is completed not from the beginning itself.Please help.

```
package com.example.shopkart;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

    public class creditcard extends Activity {
        datamanager dm;
        String[] productnamearray;
        boolean[] checkarray;
        String name,mailid,number,result;
        int[] id_array;
        EditText ccnumber;
        Button btnccconfirm;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.creditcard);
            dm=new datamanager(this);
            ccnumber=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ccnumber);
            btnccconfirm=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnccconfirm);
            productnamearray=getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("productnamearray");
            checkarray=getIntent().getExtras().getBooleanArray("checkarray");
            id_array=getIntent().getExtras().getIntArray("id_array");
            name=getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
            mailid=getIntent().getExtras().getString("mailid");

            btnccconfirm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    number=ccnumber.getText().toString();
                    if(number.length()!=16)
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"please enter a number of 16 digits",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else if(number.length()==16)
                    {
                        result=validate(number);
                    }
                    if(result=="Card is Valid")
                    {

                        dm.finalupdate(mailid,productnamearray,checkarray,id_array);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Transaction completed!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        btnccconfirm.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        onBackPressed();
                    }
                    else if(result=="Card is Invalid")
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid credit card number",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

    }
        public String validate(String ccnum)
        {
            if(ccnum.length()==16){
                char[] c = ccnum.toCharArray();
                int[] cint = new int[16];
                for(int i=0;i<16;i++){
                    if(i%2==1){
                        cint[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c[i]))*2;
                        if(cint[i] >9)
                            cint[i]=1+cint[i]%10;
                    }
                    else
                        cint[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c[i]));
                }
                int sum=0;
                for(int i=0;i<16;i++){
                    sum+=cint[i];
                }
                if(sum%10==0)
                    return "Card is Valid";
                else
                    return "Card is Invalid";
            }else
                return "Card is Invalid";
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {


        }



    }
```

I am calling the Onbackpressed() method only when the result value is Card is valid.I dont want the back button to be disabled right from the beginning.

Comment: Post some code whatever you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is really vague, not sure which action you're talking about. A bit more info would help.

Regardless, here's a generic snippet of code, just set the boolean as necessary

```
// An attribute to trigger default back pressed behaviour
protected boolean actionDone = false;

// use this to set actionDone to true, when whatever action it may be is triggered
public void onSomeActionDone()
{
    actionDone = true;
}

@ Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if (actionDone){ // use default onBackPressed behaviour, going up the navigation or exiting the app
        super.onBackPressed ();
    } else {
        // do nothing, maybe fire a toast saying: "cant go back"
    }
}
```

EDIT after the OP added their code snippet:
There's a couple things that are wrong with the code which will cause some errors:

A minor note: Check the Java convention for class naming (I use Google Java Style: https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html). Classes should start with a capital letter.

I would make `validate(String ccnum)` return a `boolean` instead of a `String`, its better practice. If you wanna print "it is valid/invalid" somewhere, just check the value of the boolean instead. Also, you can make `validate(String ccnum)` static since it's a validation method and doesn't need to manipulate object state Eg:

```
public static boolean validate(String ccnum)
{
   // ... -snip-
        if(sum%10==0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }else
        return false;
}
```

Also, be careful about your string comparison in your `onClick` method. Using `==` is not string comparison, but Object comparison. You should use `String.equals(String other)` or `String.equalsIgnoreCase(String other)` instead and be careful about where you're evaluating your `result` variable. Look for the comments with the "**" in front of it:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    number=ccnumber.getText().toString();
    if(number.length()!=16)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"please enter a number of 16 digits",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else if(number.length()==16)
    {
        result=validate(number);

        // ** moved if ... else here. The value of result will atleast be set

        if(result.equals("Card is Valid")) // more correct comparison, but as recommended above, use a boolean instead, ie : if (result)
        {
            dm.finalupdate(mailid,productnamearray,checkarray,id_array);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Transaction completed!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            btnccconfirm.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            // ** Why are you calling onBackPressed here? onBackPressed is an activity
            // method called when the android 'back' button is pressed by the user. If
            // you wanna exit out of the activity, use Activity.finish() or use 
            // activity.setResult(), then call Activity.finish() (look up the developer docs)
            onBackPressed();
        }
        else if(result.equals("Card is Invalid"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid credit card number",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

If you make `validate(String ccnum)` return a `boolean`, you can just do this instead:

```
// -SNIP-
if(validate(number))
{
    dm.finalupdate(mailid,productnamearray,checkarray,id_array);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Transaction completed!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    btnccconfirm.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    onBackPressed();
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid credit card number",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```